# allow html file to be shown in iframe django

Tags: html, django, iframe, xss

I am working on this Django project and I am trying to show the html file 'addition.html' in an iframe on 'main.html'. If I understand things correctly, I have to specify frame-ancestors options in my CSP options (as e.g. explained [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/)). However, I do not fully understand:

1. Which file can the CSP be specified?
2. What line of code is needed in order to allow my main page to show the addition in the frame.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Iframe is used for showing different page or different url you probably just want to include additional html?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: What I try to do is to include a 'sidebar' or 'panel' that can be navigated through on the left side of my website. It thus should be able to load different html files. It looks like include is a valid option for this concept, so I will check it out.